# Change the color of the Password Protected Post titles

Tags: posts, wp-admin, password, admin-css

I want to change the color of the protected post titles. When a post is in protected status (have password), the post title will turn red different from other posts. Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To change the color of password protected post titles in the admin**

In your theme or child theme, enqueue a stylesheet to load in the admin, then add some simple CSS to change the color using the class that is given to password protected posts.

In your theme's functions.php...

```
function wpse_admin_styles(){

    wp_enqueue_style(
        'admin_css', 
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/admin-styles.css', array(), filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/css/admin-styles.css') 
    );

}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_admin_styles');
```

Create a `css` directory in your theme, add the admin-styles.css and paste in the following CSS...

```
.post-password-required .row-title {
    color: red;
}
```

### [image]

**To change the color of password protected post titles on the frontend**

In your theme or child theme add the following to your CSS files, or add it directly in `Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS`.  It uses a class added to the article tag.

```
.post-password-required .entry-title {
    color: red;
}
```

### [image]

Note - This may vary from theme to theme but should give you a good idea of how to do it.